# problema al intentar hacer git pull

Tags: git, pull

Sinceramente no entiendo que sucede, siempre tengo una compilación con git. Hoy actualizaron la rama develop, así que necesito bajarme los cambios, me moví a la rama develop e hice un git status y tenía unos archivos, así que procedí a hacer git stash, pero cuándo intento hacer el git pull origin develop me muestra esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y si ejecuto git status me aparece esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

entiendo que al hacer el pull me dice que debo mover o remover esos archivos, pero por que me pide eso? como podría resolver esto para tener mi rama actualizada ?

Gracias de antemano al que me pueda ayudar.

Comment: consulta: ¿Qué sentido tiene usar una etiqueta como "problema"? ¿Acaso define en algo tu pregunta? Como usuario de más de 300 de reputación pudiste crearla, pero me parece que trae más problemas que soluciones. Lo que digo tiene que ver con https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/tagging

Answer (score 2):

`git stash` funciona con los archivos que están en el index. En tu caso esos archivos no lo están. Puedes agregarlos al index con `git add` y luego usar `git stash` para guardar su estado.

Comment: como podría agregarlos todos? sería con git add .  ? pero entonces debería hacer un commit y posteriormente un push solo para poder traerme los cambios ?

Comment: Sí, con `git add .`, no hace falta hacer el commit, con ese comando los archivos se agregan al index y ya pueden ser  afectados por `stash`.

Comment: Ok, debería de hacer git stash apply ? Dicúlpame, pero estoy confundido, esos archivos son los que estan en la rama remota y yo no los tengo, y luego cuándo haga algun commit que modifique un archivo debería de agregarlos a ese commit ?

Comment: Los archivos untracked que te indica git son los que tienes localmente no son los remotos.

Comment: bueno... veré que puedo hacer, lo que no quiero es luego de que modifique un archivo y hago commit y luego push vaya a afectar algo en el remoto.

Comment: Luego de hacer el `stash` el directorio de trabajo queda limpio. Al hacer pull se combinarán los archivos de forma normal (incluyendo los conflictos que se producen a veces). En ese punto si se modifica un archivo y se hace push de nuevo no habrá nada raro. Cuando se quiera recuperar lo que estaba en `stash`  con `stash apply` si hay archivos iguales se van a combinar y se pueden producir conflictos que hay que resolver.

Comment: @JulianProg  lo que debes de entender es el flujo de git, antes de actualizar tu repositorio local todos los archivos deben estar agregados en el `stash` esto quiere decir que tu `git` local llevará el registro de cambios de esos nuevos archivos o con los archivos nuevos en un commit, el `stash` es un paso antes del `commit ` y se diferencia porque no hay un registro en la rama, esto te sirve para llevar un versionamiento de cambios aun sin acabar y cuando ya tengas una función terminada y probada ahí realizar el commit para subir un conjunto de cambios y dejar constancia en la rama.

Comment: @RobertoEMoran Ok, muchas gracias, lo que no termino de entender, es que yo hice push de mis cambios pero estaba en otra rama que no era develop, luego el encargado hizo merge con develop. luego de yo hacer push eliminé la rama y me moví a develop ya que la idea era crear otra rama para otra función, hasta este momento no había modificado ningún archivo, no termino de entender porqué si yo no había modificado archivos y develop tiene es lo último y más actualizado simplemente no se me hace el pull sin problemas, no había tenido este inconveniente antes.

Comment: @RobertoEMoran Disculpa, tendrás un tiempo para una consulta en el chat ? si no es mucha molestia, claro.

Comment: @RobertoEMoran https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224103/git

Comment: @RobertoEMoran Hola amigo, estas por ahí? te escribí al chat.